# Slow ORDER BY with LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, full-text-search

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM location 
WHERE to_tsvector('simple',unaccent2("city"))
   @@ to_tsquery('simple',unaccent2('wroclaw')) 
order by displaycount
```

I'm happy with it:

```
"Sort  (cost=3842.56..3847.12 rows=1826 width=123) (actual time=1.915..2.084 rows=1307 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: displaycount"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 206kB"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on location  (cost=34.40..3743.64 rows=1826 width=123) (actual time=0.788..1.208 rows=1307 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent2((city)::text)) @@ '''wroclaw'''::tsquery)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on location_lower_idx  (cost=0.00..33.95 rows=1826 width=0) (actual time=0.760..0.760 rows=1307 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent2((city)::text)) @@ '''wroclaw'''::tsquery)"
"Total runtime: 2.412 ms"
```

But when I add LIMIT, the execution takes more than 2 seconds:

```
SELECT * 
FROM location 
WHERE to_tsvector('simple',unaccent2("city"))
   @@ to_tsquery('simple',unaccent2('wroclaw')) 
order by displaycount 
limit 20
```

Explain:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.00..1167.59 rows=20 width=123) (actual time=2775.452..2775.643 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using location_displaycount_index on location  (cost=0.00..106601.25 rows=1826 width=123) (actual time=2775.448..2775.637 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, unaccent2((city)::text)) @@ '''wroclaw'''::tsquery)"
"Total runtime: 2775.693 ms"
```

I think that it's some issue with ORDER BY and LIMIT. How can I force PostgreSQL to use the index and do the ordering at the end?

Subquery doesn't help:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM location 
    WHERE to_tsvector('simple',unaccent2("city"))
       @@ to_tsquery('simple',unaccent2('wroclaw')) 
    order by displaycount
) t 
LIMIT 20;
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM location 
    WHERE to_tsvector('simple',unaccent2("city"))
       @@ to_tsquery('simple',unaccent2('wroclaw'))
) t 
order by displaycount 
LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that this would fix your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   location 
WHERE     to_tsvector('simple',unaccent2(city))
       @@ to_tsquery('simple',unaccent2('wroclaw')) 
ORDER  BY to_tsvector('simple',unaccent2(city))
       @@ to_tsquery('simple',unaccent2('wroclaw')) DESC
         ,displaycount 
LIMIT  20;
```

I repeat the `WHERE` condition as first element of the `ORDER BY` clause - which is logically redundant, but should keep the query planner from assuming it would be better off processing rows according to the index `location_displaycount_index` - which turns out to be much more expensive.

The underlying problem is that the query planner obviously grossly misjudges the selectivity and / or cost of your `WHERE` condition. I can only speculate why that is.

Do you have [autovacuum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) running - which should also take care of running `ANALYZE` on your tables? Thereby, are your table-statistics up-to-date? Any effect if you run:

```
ANALYZE location;
```

And try again?

It can also be that the selectivity of the [`@@` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-OPERATORS-TABLE) is being misjudged. I would imagine that it is very hard to estimate for logical reasons.

---

If my query should not solve the problem, and generally to verify the underlying theory do **one of these two** things:

- temporarily delete the index `location_displaycount_index`
- temporarily [disable basic index scans](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) by running:

  ```
  SET enable_indexscan = OFF;
  ```

The latter is less intrusive and only affects the current session. It leaves the methods `bitmap heap scan` and `bitmap index scan` open, which are used by the faster plan.
Then re-run the query.

BTW: If the theory is sound, your query (as you have it now) will be much faster with a less selective search term in the FTS condition - contrary to what you might expect. Try it.

Comment: The query works. Turning the indexscan off works too. ANALYZE doesn't work. Thank you very much for comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using a LIMIT postgresql adjust it's plan to be optimal for only retrieving the subset of row. Unfortunatly it somehow makes a wrong choice in your case. This could be because the statistics for the table are too old. Try updating the statistic by issuing VACUUM ANALYZE location;

Forcing the use of indexes is normally done by disallowing the use of sequential scans (set enable_seqscan=false). However in your case it isn't doing a sequential scan it just switches to a different index for the query with the LIMIT.

In case the analyze doesn't help could you tell which version of postgresql you are using? Also how many rows are there in the table?

Comment: Analyze didn't help. The table has about 36000 rows and I'm using postgresql 9.1.